# How to implement a lookup value in property grid property

Tags: c#, lookup, propertygrid

Using C#, Winforms, PropertyGrid.

Lets say I have the following class:

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public int Key;
   public Guid LookupKey;
}


//This class is a lookup class
public class Lookup
{
  public Guid Key;
  public string Description;
}
```

e.g. Data for lookup table

```
Key                  Description   
[SomeGuidValue1]     Value1  
[SomeGuidValue2]     Value2


SomeClass.LookupKey = Lookup.Key
```

Now.. I already have the UIEditor showing a DataGridView containing the values for the Lookup table. But in the propertygrid.. I have the Guid value displaying instead of the description. How can I show the description whilst maintaining the Guid (Key) in the propertygrid property? i.e. I want to display Value1 instead of [SomeGuidValue1] but it should keep the reference to [SomeGuidValue1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.8), something like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int Key { get; set; }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(LookupConverter))]
    public Guid LookupKey { get; set; }
}

public class LookupConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string)) //property grid will ask for this
        {
            var key = (Guid)value;
            return ConvertGuidToDescription(...) // TODO: implement this
        }

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```